# CoffeeScript for loops can't take multiple actions?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How is the first one different from the second? The first one works as intended but the second is not doing what I am expecting. In the first one i am making the call indirectly through callToPhotos but in the second one i make a call to getPhotos straight away and pass in the albums.
Why and how is this is different?

```
$.ajax
    method:'get'
    url: '/slides/facebook-albums'
    success: (albums) ->
        renderAlbums(albums)
        callToPhotos(albums)

renderAlbums = (albums) ->
    for album in albums
        $('#facebook .main').append("<div id='#{ album['id'] }' class='album-info'><a class='#{album['id']} fb-album' href='#'>#{album['name']}</a>
        <img src=#{album['cover_photo']} width='100' height= '100' class='#{album['id']} fb-album'></div>")

callToPhotos = (albums) ->
    for album in albums
        getPhotos(album)

getPhotos = (album) ->
      $.ajax
        method: "get"
        url: "/slides/#{album['id']}/photos"
        success: (photos) ->
          renderPhotos(photos, album['id'])
```

--

```
$.ajax
    method:'get'
    url: '/slides/facebook-albums'
    success: (albums) ->
        renderAlbums(albums)
        # callToPhotos(albums)
        getPhotos(albums)

renderAlbums = (albums) ->
    for album in albums
        $('#facebook .main').append("<div id='#{ album['id'] }' class='album-info'><a class='#{album['id']} fb-album' href='#'>#{album['name']}</a>
        <img src=#{album['cover_photo']} width='100' height= '100' class='#{album['id']} fb-album'></div>")

callToPhotos = (albums) ->
    for album in albums
        getPhotos(album)

getPhotos = (albums) ->
    for album in albums
      $.ajax
        method: "get"
        url: "/slides/#{album['id']}/photos"
        success: (photos) ->
          renderPhotos(photos, album['id'])
```

Comment: it seems, these codes are similar, both of them need to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with variable scoping in the second snippet's loop. You can introduce an immediately invoked function (IIF) to solve it (read about the `do` keyword at the bottom of the http://coffeescript.org/#loops section =D):

```
getPhotos = (albums) ->
  for album in albums
    do (album) ->
      $.ajax
        method: "get"
        url: "/slides/#{album['id']}/photos"
        success: (photos) ->
          renderPhotos(photos, album['id'])
  return
```

I do recommend you to use your first approach though, as it's the same as the IIF but i think more clear, as the extra function now has a descriptive variable name; maybe declaring the function inside the `getPhotos` function:

```
getPhotos = (albums) ->
  getAlbum = (album) ->
    $.ajax
      method: "get"
      url: "/slides/#{album['id']}/photos"
      success: (photos) ->
        renderPhotos(photos, album['id'])

  getAlbum album for album in albums

  return
```

(notice that in both cases i added an empty `return` so that it doesn't generate and return an array comprehension as its last expression =P)

Comment: Do you know of a canonical version of this answer? I'm pretty sure there are hundreds of copies of the same thing and both of us have probably answered it dozens of times :)

Comment: @muistooshort, nope. I was thinking about the same thing. In fact, i thought to myself "this time i'm gonna do a very short answer!"... and i failed =P